# GridView update causes "incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'" error

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a major problem when trying to use update in a `GridView`. From the code below, once I  click 'edit', I get the option to change the 'KPI' name and 'Current Target'.  But, once I click 'update', I get an error message:

> incorrect sysntax near 'nvarchar'

Here is my markup:

```
<p>
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="GroupSelection" runat="server" DataSourceID="Group" DataTextField="FcstGroup"
        DataValueField="FcstGroup">
    </asp:DropDownList>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WFMConnectionString3 %>"
        SelectCommand="select 
                            case _parameter.name as KPI,
                            [target]*100 as [Current Target]
                            from _parameter inner join _reporting_group
                            on _parameter.reporting_group = _reporting_group.id

                            where _reporting_group.name = @WG " 
UpdateCommand="update _parameter set target = .80
                                where reporting_group = (select ID from _reporting_group where name = @WG)
                                and name = 'nco_i_e' ">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GroupSelection" Name="WG" PropertyName="SelectedItem.text" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GroupSelection" Name="WG" PropertyName="SelectedItem.text" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Group" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WFMConnectionString3 %>"
    SelectCommand=" SELECT     distinct _reporting_group.name AS FcstGroup
FROM         dbo._metrics INNER JOIN  
                  dbo._reporting_group ON dbo._metrics.reporting_group = dbo._reporting_group.id ">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I'm guessing that the problem is with the update command, but this is working correctly when ran in SQL:

```
UpdateCommand="update _parameter set target = .80
                                where reporting_group = (select ID from _reporting_group where name = @WG)
                                and name = 'nco_i_e' ">
```

Note that, at the moment, the update command is just using a fixed set 'target' value and a fixed 'name' value. Eventually, I will need to use the value entered in the 'Current Target' and the KPI value. But, I will get to this once I can figure out why I'm getting the 'nvarchar' error message.

If someone can spot where the issue is, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Just curious, did you ever resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that jumps out at me as that you should change your UpdateParameter to just this:

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GroupSelection" Name="WG" PropertyName="SelectedItem.Text" />
```

`SelectedItem.text` is not a valid property (the `.Text` should be capitalized).

Other things that could possibly cause a problem would be your data types in SQL.  If your "target" column can't accept a value of .80, or if your "name" value can't accept whatever you're selecting in the "GroupSelection" DropDownList, that could possibly cause this type of syntax error.